# More Pythonic/Pandaic approach to looping over a pandas Series

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy

This is most likely something very basic, but I can't figure it out. 
Suppose that I have a Series like this:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

How can I do operations on sub-series of this Series without having to revert to using a for-loop?

Suppose, for example, that I want to turn it into a new Series that contains four elements. The first element in this new Series is the sum of the first three elements in the original Series (1, 1, 1), the second the sum of the second three (2, 2, 2), etc.:

```
s2 = pd.Series([3, 6, 9, 12])
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reshape the series s1 using numpy and then sum over the rows such as:

```
np.sum(np.array(s1).reshape(len(s1)/3,3), axis = 1)
```

which results in

```
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12], dtype=int64)
```

EDIT: as [MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393381/mseifert) mentioned in his comment, you can also let numpy compute the length such as:

```
np.sum(np.array(s1).reshape(-1, 3), axis=1)
```

Comment: Neat. And faster than my answer.

Comment: Yet your answer is more robust since it also works if s1 has length which is not a multiple of 3

Comment: Instead of calculating the length yourself you can also tell numpy to calculcate it: `np.sum(np.array(s1).reshape(-1, 3), axis=1)`

Comment: Great! This approach is simple and solves my question almost directly. For these reasons accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) by specifying the slices to be reduced at every 3rd element and compute their running sum:

```
>>> pd.Series(np.add.reduceat(s1.values, np.arange(0, s1.shape[0], 3)))
0     3
1     6
2     9
3    12
dtype: int64
```

***Timing Constraints:***

```
arr = np.repeat(np.arange(10**5), 3)
s = pd.Series(arr)
s.shape
(300000,)

# @IanS soln
%timeit s.rolling(3).sum()[2::3]        
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop

# @Divakar soln
%timeit pd.Series(np.bincount(np.arange(s.size)//3, s))  
100 loops, best of 3: 5.44 ms per loop

# @Nikolas Rieble soln
%timeit pd.Series(np.sum(np.array(s).reshape(len(s)/3,3), axis = 1))  
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop

# @Nikolas Rieble modified soln
%timeit pd.Series(np.sum(np.array(s).reshape(-1, 3), axis=1))  
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop

# @Divakar modified soln
%timeit pd.Series(s.values.reshape(-1,3).sum(1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop

# Proposed solution in post
%timeit pd.Series(np.add.reduceat(s.values, np.arange(0, s.shape[0], 3)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop
```

Comment: It's added for a considerable length of the series following the same pattern.

Comment: I think a faster version with summing would be getting the views : `%timeit pd.Series(s.values.reshape(-1,3).sum(1))`.

Comment: @Divakar, It's definitely faster. You can edit your post if you'd like.

Comment: Added one more soln in my post and added timing results correspondingly.

Comment: `np.einsum` is indeed the fastest of them all. Well done!

Comment: And yours being a good mix of being generic and performant :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a NumPy approach using [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to handle generic number of elements -

```
pd.Series(np.bincount(np.arange(s1.size)//3, s1))
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 9, 5])

In [43]: pd.Series(np.bincount(np.arange(s1.size)//3, s1))
Out[43]: 
0     3.0
1     6.0
2     9.0
3    12.0
4    14.0
dtype: float64
```

---

If we are really craving for performance and for case when the length of the series is divisible by the window length, we can get the view into the series with `s1.values`, then `reshape` and finally use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for summation, like so -

```
pd.Series(np.einsum('ij->i',s.values.reshape(-1,3)))
```

Timings with the same benchmark dataset as used in [`@Nickil Maveli's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486008/3293881) -

```
In [140]: s = pd.Series(np.repeat(np.arange(10**5), 3))

# @Nickil Maveli's soln
In [141]: %timeit pd.Series(np.add.reduceat(s.values, np.arange(0, s.shape[0], 3)))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.07 ms per loop

# Using views+sum
In [142]: %timeit pd.Series(s.values.reshape(-1,3).sum(1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop

# Using views+einsum
In [143]: %timeit pd.Series(np.einsum('ij->i',s.values.reshape(-1,3)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

This computes the rolling sum:

```
s1.rolling(3).sum()
```

You simply need to select every third element:

```
s1.rolling(3).sum()[2::3]
```

Output:

```
2      3.0
5      6.0
8      9.0
11    12.0
```

Comment: Clean. Why are first 2 values NaN?

Comment: The first 2 values are NaN because you need at least 3 values to calculate the rolling sum. You can change that: `s1.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()`.