# Calculate the sum of every 5 elements in a python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python array in which I want to calculate the sum of every 5 elements. In my case I have the array `c` with ten elements.  (In reality it has a lot more elements.)

```
c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So finally I would like to have a new array (`c_new`) which should show the sum of the first 5 elements, and the second 5 elements

So the result should be that one

```
1+0+0+0+0 = 1
2+0+0+0+0 = 2

c_new = [1, 2]
```

Thank you for your help
    Markus

Comment: Here's one for pandas series, should be applicable as it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485471/more-pythonic-pandorable-approach-to-looping-over-a-pandas-series

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `np.add.reduceat` by passing indices where you want to split and sum:

```
import numpy as np
c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
np.add.reduceat(c, np.arange(0, len(c), 5))
# array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you everybody, this is really a elegant method!

Answer (score 11):

Heres one way of doing it -

```
c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
print [sum(c[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(c), 5)]
```

Result -

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: mine was similar: `[sum(x for x in c[i*5:5*(i+1)]) for i in range(len(c)//5)]` but yours is better

Comment: I tend to use the `grouper` recipe from the itertools doc for this kind of thing, https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes - `[sum(group) for group in grouper(c, 5, 0)]` Though it might be overkill here.

Comment: The itertools recipes have some great stuff in them.

Answer (score 5):

If five divides the length of your vector and it is contiguous then

```
np.reshape(c, (-1, 5)).sum(axis=-1)
```

It also works if it is non contiguous, but then it is typically less efficient.

Benchmark:

```
def aredat():
    return np.add.reduceat(c, np.arange(0, len(c), 5))

def reshp():
    np.reshape(c, (-1, 5)).sum(axis=-1)

c = np.random.random(10_000_000)

timeit(aredat, number=100)
3.8516048429883085
timeit(reshp, number=100)
3.09542763303034
```

So where possible, `reshape`ing seems a bit faster; `reduceat` has the advantage of gracefully handling non-multiple-of-five vectors.

Comment: @Divakar Why on earth is it so much faster? `.sum` is arguably the most mainstream function there is. It should have optimisations coming out of its ears!

Comment: AFAIK it avoids few checks, but yeah pretty sad for `sum`! :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this ?

```
np.array([np.sum(i, axis = 0) for i in c.reshape(c.shape[0]//5,5,c.shape[1])])
```

Comment: Why indeed. Why should OP use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve that. Will leave, below, two options using `numpy` built-in methods.

---

**Option 1**

[`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) as follows

```
c_sum = np.sum(np.array(c).reshape(-1, 5), axis=1)

[Out]: array([1, 2])
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), a custom lambda function, and [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) as follows

```
c_sum = np.vectorize(lambda x: sum(c[x:x+5]))(np.arange(0, len(c), 5))

[Out]: array([1, 2])
```