# How to add every four elements in a 1D column array (1,35040) in Python

Tags: python

I tried it using array indexing method in for loop. But it is raising 'ValueError: too many values to unpack(expected 1)'

Comment: Kindly share the snippet of code that you've tried.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve: is it to add something to every multiple of 4 in the array or are you trying to compact the array, summing every 4 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want (replace `arr` by what you have):

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]).reshape((12,1))
result = [sum(a[i:i+4]) for i in np.arange(0, len(arr), 4) ]
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
[10, 26, 42]
```

Similar question has been also answered here: [Calculate the sum of every 5 elements in a python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444046/calculate-the-sum-of-every-5-elements-in-a-python-array)

Comment: Thank you Ankit :)